# How can i enter an image url and get an image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('[name="thumbnail"]').on('change', function() {
     $('img.preview').prop('src', this.value);
});
```

```html
<input name="thumbnail" placeholder="Post image URL here" />
<br />
<img src="http://webspace.webring.com/people/jv/vladilyich/preview.gif" class="preview" />
```

i'm looking for something to work like the js fiddle example.
but only i want it to work if a user were to enter img5.jpg for example, an image saved on desktop in the same directory as the index.html folder

Comment: You cannot load local files programmatically via javascript. However, it is possible to load image if a full www url is provided like "http://somedomain.com/image.png"

Comment: i'm talking about an image that is stored in a folder under a name called img5.jpg for example along with the index.html file . and when you type img.5.jpg into the text box and click the button it will show the photo on the screen. It won't stay when the page reloads I don't want it to stay or store when the page reloads

Comment: this is the website. i want the photo upload almost like my post status function.     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2CVq6cUswwtZ29LVDBuQjBDalk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is the website used for online or offline?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/EFkW2/

Comment: the website will be used offline

Comment: any way to do  this?????????

Comment: the jsfiddle u commented works. what else u want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Image preview</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   
   $('#imgName').bind('input', function() {
       $('#imageHolder').attr('src', $(this).val()); //concatinate path if required
   });

  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="" id="imgName" value="" placeholder="Input image name"><br><br>
 <img name="imageHolder" id="imageHolder" src="http://i.imgur.com/zAyt4lX.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Now I just need to paste the image URL into the text input and that is all.