# How to preview an image coming through a link beofore it is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML input box as shown below in which I want to preview an image coming through a link before it is submitted.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sd0xr16L/) for it. What I want is after **placing a image URL in the input box**, 
it should display an image in the `Powered by HTML.COM` placeholder section.

**This is what I have tried:**

**HTML:**

```
<input type='link' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

**Problem Statement:**

The above **HTML/JS** is working perfectly fine when the `input type ='file'`. I am wondering what changes I should make in the script above 
so that it works when the `input type ='link'`

Comment: There is no such thing as an input with type `link`

Comment: ok, what would be the best way to achieve that ? All my images are coming through a link and I want to preview it before sending it.

Comment: You can create a hidden link that executes the `click` event for the file input. `<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();">Click Me</a>` Then you do what you're already doing.

Comment: Keep in mind that the comment above is not an answer. It's just an example of how to open the file select dialog using a link with an existing file input on the page...

Comment: @daddygames can you give me a demo on fiddle ?

Comment: Please let me know if this helps and I'll make it an answer -> https://jsfiddle.net/u4h5L3v9/3/

Comment: I found the answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169532/how-can-i-enter-an-image-url-and-get-an-image-preview). i am looking for something similar to that.

Comment: So, to clarify... You want a solution that accepts a URL to an image and previews it in an element on the page. Correct? The link you provided shows that solution. do you need any help then or is this now a duplicate post of the one you linked to?